# Cerrar JFrame cuando abro otro

Tags: java, java-swing

Tego un JFrame"1" con un boton que abre otro, cuando apreto el boton y el JFrame"2" se abre, quiero que el JFrame"1" se cierre. He intentado hacerlo de las siguientes maneras:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no me han funcionado.

Comment: Ven si se abre pero el otro frame no se cierra o no se realiza ninguna de las dos acciones?

Comment: Si, en el boton el frame se abre, pero el frame de donde lo abri no se cierra. @Sergio1871

Comment: Eso lo llamas desde un método un listener o desde el constructor? desde donde lo estas llamando?

Comment: Añade el codigo que mas puedas es dificil saber que estas haciendo con tus Frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres que el JFrame se cierre al abrir otro, entonces simplemente "botalo" con **dispose();**

***EJEMPLO***

En el JFrame1 en el evento de tu boton, colocarias algo asi:

```
Ventana2 frame2 = new Ventana2();
dispose();
```

Y en el JFrame2... en tu evento de salir....

```
dispose();
Ventana1 frame1 = new Ventana1();
```

Y ya muere el caso.

**OJO:** asegurate de haber establecido correctamente las propiedades de **setDefaultCloseOperation** del frame. En tu caso, te conviene que en el JFrame2 establescas **DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE**.

***Actualización:***

Te la pongo mas facil de comprender con un ejemplo sencillo, crearemos 2 JFrames.

El JFrame1 que sera "Ventana1":

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author Phillips
 */
public class Ventana1 extends JFrame{
    private JButton boton;
    public Ventana1(){
        super("Dumb Demo");
        setSize(300,300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        boton = new JButton("Abre otra ventana");
        boton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                Ventana2 obj = new Ventana2();
                dispose();
            }
        });
        add(boton);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

El JFrame2 que sera "Ventana2":

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
/**
 *
 * @author Phillips
 */
public class Ventana2 extends JFrame{
    private JButton boton;
    public Ventana2(){
        super("Segunda Ventana");
        setSize(300,300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        boton = new JButton("Soy el segundo boton de otra ventana");
        boton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                dispose();
                Ventana1 obj = new Ventana1();
            }
        });
        add(boton);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

La clase main que la necesitamos siempre como launcher:

```
public class Demo {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ventana1 prueba = new Ventana1();
}  
}
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si apretas el boton de la primera ventana, aparecera la segunda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes tomarte la molestia si quieres de buscar la otra ventana para comprobar que todo esta en su lugar. (Si vuelves a dar clic en el boton de la segunda ventana, se cerrara esta y aparecera la primera)

Answer (score 2):

Tengo esta línea de código en un proyecto y me sirve para que cuando abro una jframe el otro se cierre.

Vista obj=new Vista();
        obj.setVisible(true);
        dispose();

Comment: Tampoco me estaria funcionando, se abre el 2do frame pero sigue sin cerrarse el anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Hola buenas para los nuevos en esto como yo, la linea de codigo `dispose();` va primero antes de las lineas de codigo que abren la ventada deseada. ejemplo:

ventanda a es donde estas y quieres ir a ventada b.

(nombre de la clase de ventada b porque a esa ventana quieres ir) variable = new nombre del constructor.

```
ventadab ir = new ventadab(); // esto si esta en la misma carpeta o folder
 nombredelfolder.ventadab ir = new ventadab(); // si estan en diferentes folder y arriba en las librerias llamas al folder y el jfram donde esta el constructor.
```

y ya en el boton que hara la tarea.

```
dispose(); //cierras la ventada a para ir a la ventana b
  ventadab ir new ventadab();
  ir.setVisible(true);
```